# Why am i not able to make facebook c# sdk 4.1 sample work?

Tags: facebook, silverlight-4.0

I have setup my application on facebook and changed the appid and secretkey in the sample. When i click login to facebook a popup does come but when i enter my username and password for facebook it keeps failing. To be specific this function is fails :-

```
[ScriptableMember]
        public void LoggedIn(string uri) //string sessionKey, string sessionSecret, int expires, string userId, string allowedPermissions)
        {
            FacebookAuthenticationResult authResult;
            if (FacebookAuthenticationResult.TryParse(uri, out authResult))
            {
                fbApp.Session = authResult.ToSession();
                loginSucceeded();
            }
            else
            {
                failedLogin();
            }
        }
```

and to be specific this line fails

```
 if (FacebookAuthenticationResult.TryParse(uri, out authResult))
```

I do get the uri which is

http://localhost:18201/LoginSuccessful.htm#access_token=somaccesstoeknrandomstring&expires_in=5894

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have same problem, did you solve this problem?